# Disabling keyboard of windows phone having focus on Textbox

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new in Windows Phone.

In my app I have a textbox where cursor will continuously blink for input at first. I have a custom dialpad to take input from users. So I have to disable the Windows Phone Keyboard.

After searching online, most of the solution is based on removing the focus from textbox to hide the keyboard.

In my case, its not happening since keyboard pops up and hide instantly.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Another thing: I also need the cursor to be blinking in textbox.**

Comment: can you please provide  some code snippets

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you, create GotFocus event of your textbox.

```
GotFocus="input_GotFocus"
private void input_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
this.Focus();
}
```

Comment: I know this but in my case its not working. This removes the focus from textbox but i need the focus for blinking cursor with keyboard hiddedn.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be to not use TextBox at all. Instead, you can use a simple TextBlock and on tap on the TextBlock, open your custom keypad. You can probably toggle visibility of the keypad to hide/unhide it. on key press of the keypad, update the text of the TextBlock.

EDIT : Adding a sample code for this (with cursor implementation as well)

Xaml for my custom TextBox implementation :

```
<Border x:Name="brdTextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100"
                Margin="10">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtEnterText" FontSize="28" Foreground="Black" Margin="0"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtCursor" FontSize="28" Foreground="Black" Text="|" Margin="0"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
```

A sample code behind, that uses timer to control the tick of the cursor :

```
Timer timer = new Timer((obj) => 
        {
            Dispatcher pageDispatcher = obj as Dispatcher;

            pageDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
            {
                if (txtCursor.Text == "|")
                {
                    txtCursor.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    txtCursor.Text = "|";
                }
            });

        }, this.Dispatcher, 1000, 1000);
```

After this, you can probably bring up your keypad on border tap, and on key event of the keypad, fill up the textblock. You can tweak the timer duration and intervals to achieve a close resemblance to the actual cursor.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Textblock is not selectable.....so there is no way for blinking cursor in textblock or changing the cursor position.